# UPDATE QUERY IN IOS

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have used following the Table(emp) in my product.

```
+-----+------+---------+------+-----------+-----+
| id  | name | Manager | dept | ismanager | DOJ |
+-----+------+---------+------+-----------+-----+
| 101 | XXX  | YYY     |    1 |         0 |     |
| 102 | XX   | YY      |    2 |         0 |     |
| 103 | XXX  | YYY     |    1 |         0 |     |
| 104 | XX   | YY      |    2 |         0 |     |
| 105 | XXX  | kkk     |    2 |         0 |     |
| 106 | XX   | zzz     |    2 |         0 |     |
| 107 | XXX  | YYY     |    2 |         0 |     |
+-----+------+---------+------+-----------+-----+
```

I want to edit the isManager column based on the 'dept' and Manager column. if the records, match both manager and dept that time only i have to update.

I have tried the following query,

```
update managertable set ismanager = '1' where manager IN(select manager from managertable group by manager,dept  having count(*) > 1).
```

But it update all the records, as per the example I want to update only 101 and 103. 107 should not get update because that dept is different. Please suggest some idea and save my time

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS. This is a basic SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is pretty close.  The only difference is that you want to look for `name`s that match `manager`s, which is a small change to the `where` clause:

```
update managertable
     set ismanager = '1
      where name IN (select manager
                     from managertable
                     group by manager,dept 
                     having count(*) > 1
                    )
```